# ServerApplication cannot see file with relative path

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I have an application that extends ServerApplication. Instead of relying on configuration files being in the pre-defined locations ServerApplication uses I want the user to be forced to pass the path to the file via a command line flag:

`myapp -f path/to/my/file --daemon`

My problem is that with the --daemon flag I cannot pass a relative path as ServerApplication cannot see the file, I need to pass a full path: `/path/to/my/file`. If the `--daemon` flag is not passed, the application is capable of seeing the file.

I know that once the application daemonizes it changes its directory to `/` but I'm reading the file in `ApplicationServer::initialize` and printing the value of `application.dir` shows the correct path.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *application.dir* is not the same as the current working directory. In fact, Util::ServerApplication [changes it explicitly](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/9d259ac02f880a486ebef30acc4e5e83d3e87b5f/Util/src/ServerApplication.cpp#L603) to root, which is consistent with default daemon behavior.

Comment: But the documentation says that's done between the initialisation, which I take to mean the call to `void ServerApplication::initialize(Application& self)` and `int ServerApplication::main(const vector<string>& args)`. When is the directory changed then?

Comment: It is changed where [the documentation says](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.ServerApplication.html) - "After the initialization is complete, but before entering the main() method".I think you are mixing *application.dir* with *current working directory*. They are not the same thing, application.dir is directory where the executable is located. Current working directory is where e.g. a file will be written if you only specify file name, without directory path.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Isn't initialisation and main() the two methods I highlighted above? Because I read the file in `initialize(Application& self)` but at that point the application has already moved to a different directory.

Comment: Then it has not moved to a different directory, but rather remained in "/". See what your platform documentation says about it.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer because the application is indeed moving to a different directory but the documentation is not clear enough. Will review what's happening.